# How can I get image data while the image is still loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, download, filereader

I have a content script that puts images through a filter but currently waits for the entire image to be downloaded first before it starts processing.

How can I format a function to request the image and get the raw image data in chunks as it comes in?

I'd want to try to process image chunks in something like every 200ish pixels but would need to play with it to find the best size. I thought maybe I could do it by requesting a data stream for the image file but I only found documentation for video streams and have no idea what filereader I would use for a partial image.

Comment: Image decoders are complex beasts and you cannot write your own. So to achieve this you would have to reengineer open source code, identify places where a chunk is read and stored to memory and hack your own logic in there. Requires high skills, is format dependent, and... virtually impossible.

Comment: The JPEF format has an explicit provision for progressive transmission, i.e. supplying successive versions of the same image with increasing resolution, for pre-visualization purposes. But that does not seem to be what you are after.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yeah unfortunately I'm not working with images I have control over so I can't decide what format they will be. Thanks for answering, no wonder I can't find any documentation if it's such a hard thing to do

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: It's for a browser extension. Not only could I show the filtering sooner with a partially complete image but the entire operation would finish sooner.

Comment: I see no better way that to *magically* track where in the image buffer the decoder is writing the image as it decodes it and start processing when you have enough data. But nothing guarantees that a decoder starts decoding before it has seen the whole file, nor that it will write data contiguously.

Comment: Personal opinion, I would not believe that much in the user reacting immediately, before having seen the whole filtered image. But indeed, the entire operation finishes somewhat sooner.

Comment: You can fill the image buffer with a known pattern, and let the processing thread polls memory and advance as the pattern is overwritten. This assumes that the image buffer is available beforehand. You will also need to know the image width before processing can start.

Comment: Yeah my current solution is to show the image the classical way until it's loaded since the browser handles at least displaying the plain image as it loads. Whatever decoder the browser uses outputs pixels one line at a time. I'm guessing that decoder wouldn't be available in javascript though.

Comment: So that should make my solution viable.